# Sorted Binary Tree

Tags: python, tree, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is the array I use for BT:

```
bt_array = [10, 3, 15, 1, None, 9]
```

This is the code I use currently.

```
def sorted_array(self): # NEEDS FIX
    # TODO: should return a sorted array
    elements=[]
    if self.left:
        elements += self.left.sorted_array()

    elements.append(self.internal_array)

    if self.right:
        elements += self.right.sorted_array()

    return elements
```

it returns this:

```
sorted array [1, 3, None, 10, 9, 15]
```

but I would like to get it in order smth like this:

```
 sorted array [None, 1, 3, 9, 10, 15]
```

Or None can stay where it did, but 9 should be before 10.

Comment: The array is not a valid binary tree, that's why u get a wrong result.

Comment: Ok, how can I validate it?

Comment: ```[10, 3, 15, 1,9, null]```

Answer (score -1):

The input `[10, 3, 15, 1, None, 9]` describes this tree:

```
       10
      /  \
     3    15
    /    /
   1    9
```

This is not a valid binary *search* tree. The value 9 should have been a right child of 3. Since the input is wrong, the output cannot be trusted. If such input is expected, you should [verify that a tree is a valid BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645209/validate-binary-search-tree).

Moreover, this input format is typically used by code challenge sites (e.g. Leet Code), and the `None` values only serve as stubs to describe the tree unambiguously with a level-order traversal. These `None` values are not supposed to be included in the output.

If your code produces a list with `None` values, then it means you created node instances that have an attribute `internal_array` that is `None`. Such nodes should not exist in the tree. It is also confusing that this attribute is called that way, as it should certainly *not* hold an array as value, but a simple number.

Here is some code you could use:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None): 
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    @classmethod
    def from_level_order(Node, values):
        dummy = Node()
        queue = [dummy]
        isright = True
        for value in values:
            node = None if value is None else Node(value)
            if isright:
                queue.pop(0).right = node
            else:
                queue[0].left = node
            if node:
                queue.append(node)
            isright = not isright
        return dummy.right                

    def is_bst(self, lower = float('-inf'), upper = float('inf')):
        return (lower <= self.data <= upper
                and (not self.right or self.right.is_bst(self.data, upper))
                and (not self.left or self.left.is_bst(lower, self.data))
        )
    
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left:
            yield from self.left
        yield self.data
        if self.right:
            yield from self.right
```

Now for the example input you gave, we can tell that it is not a valid BST with the following code:

```
tree = Node.from_level_order([10, 3, 15, 1, None, 9])
print(tree.is_bst())  # False
```

If we correct the input (changing 9 to 11), we can use the above `__iter__` method (similar to your function) to get the sorted list:

```
tree = Node.from_level_order([10, 3, 15, 1, None, 11])
print(tree.is_bst())  # True
print(list(tree))  # [1, 3, 10, 11, 15]
```